# Converting timestamps for RNN use

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have stamps in the form of 2016-01-01 00:00:00. Is there a simple method to convert this timestamp for my RNN? Is there a pandas function?

Comment: What are you using for your RNN?

Comment: @AKX keras to build it. Is that your question?